# Yahoo Boss API Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, json, pagination, yahoo-api

I am getting this json output from yahoo boss api. It goes on for 50 results, but, I have pasted only the first two...

```
    (
        [bossresponse] =&gt; stdClass Object
            (
                [responsecode] =&gt; 200
                [web] =&gt; stdClass Object
            (
                [start] =&gt; 0
                [count] =&gt; 50
                [totalresults] =&gt; 2750000
                [results] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
                            (
                                [date] =&gt; 
                                [clickurl] =&gt; http://www.apple.com/ipad/
                                [url] =&gt; http://www.apple.com/ipad/
                                [dispurl] =&gt; www.apple.com/<b>ipad</b>
                                [title] =&gt; Apple - <b>iPad</b>
                                [abstract] =&gt; <b>iPad</b> is a magical window where nothing comes between you and what you love. And it comes in two sizes.
                            )

                        [1] =&gt; stdClass Object
                            (
                                [date] =&gt; 
                                [clickurl] =&gt; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad
                                [url] =&gt; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad
                                [dispurl] =&gt; en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<b>IPad</b>
                                [title] =&gt; <b>iPad</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
                                [abstract] =&gt; The <b>iPad</b> is a line of tablet computers designed and marketed by Apple Inc., which runs Apple's iOS operating system. The first <b>iPad</b> was released on April 3, 2010; the ...
                            )

                        [2] =&gt; stdClass Object
                            (
                                [date] =&gt; 
                                [clickurl] =&gt; http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1&amp;rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aipad
                                [url] =&gt; http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1&amp;rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aipad
                                [dispurl] =&gt; www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&amp;page=1&amp;rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A<b>ipad</b>
                                [title] =&gt; Amazon.com: <b>ipad</b>
                                [abstract] =&gt; Considering an <b>iPad</b>? Compare it to Kindle Fire HD Check out our easy side-by-side comparison chart to see how the newest <b>iPad</b> stacks up to Kindle Fire HD 8.9".
                            )
```

I use the following code in php to connect to the api and display the results...

```
      **//connect to yahoo api and get results in json**
      <?php
      require("OAuth.php");

    $cc_key  = "**confidential**";
    $cc_secret = "**confidential**";
    $url = "http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web";
    $args = array();
    $args["q"] = "yahoo";
    $args["format"] = "json";

    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($cc_key, $cc_secret);
    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, NULL,"GET", $url, $args);
    $request->sign_request(new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), $consumer, NULL);
    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($args));
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array($request->to_header());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
    $results = json_decode($rsp);
    ?>
    **// Present results in html/php**
    <div id="resultsdiv">
    <?php
     foreach($results->bossresponse->web->results as $result) 
      {
echo '<h3><a href='.$result->url.'>'.$result->title.'</br>'.$result->abstract.'</a></h3>';
}
      ?>
```

My question is how do I paginate results, since all the 50 results appear on the first web page only. I want to display ten results in every page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Yahoo! BOSS documentation, specifically the [Universal Arguments section](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/v2_univer_api_args.html), it looks like you can use the `start` and `count` parameters to adjust the pagination of results. It looks like the default return count is 50 which matches what you observed.

In your code example you can adjust by adding:

```
$args["start"] = 0; // increment as needed
$args["count"] = 10;
```